# What are the two sections of this dmidecode output?

Tags: multiprocessor, dmidecode

I ran dmidecode on my system to verify certain processor information. However, I am not sure what the two sections of the output indicate.

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t processor
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU 1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer:                  
    ID: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    Version:                                                
    Voltage: 3.3 V 2.9 V
    External Clock: Unknown
    Max Speed: 2000 MHz
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Status: Unpopulated
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0007
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 1
    Core Enabled: 1
    Thread Count: 1
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: P0
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: E-Series
    Manufacturer: AuthenticAMD

    Signature: Family 11, Model 15, Stepping 15
    Flags:
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
    Version: AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
    Voltage: 1.4 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 1650 MHz
    Current Speed: 1650 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: None
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x002D
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x002E
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 2
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
```

The second section (`Handle 0x0035`) seems to be the processor information. What is the first section (`Handle 0x0004`) ? I have looked at the manpage, and some Google results as well, none of which were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this man page entry](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man8/dmidecode.8.html), I see that,

> Some keywords may return more than one result on some systems (e.g. 
>   processor-version on a  multi-processor system).

So as per your output, your system seems to be a multiprocessor which is why you are getting 2 handles information returned.

Also from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/181733) answer, I see that,

> For example, if the BIOS detects a dual-core processor, it would
>   report a value of 2 if it leaves both cores enabled, and it would
>   report a value of 1 if it disables multi-core support.

**Alright, my system is not multiprocessor. Why is it returning 2 handler values?**

[see here in the bugs section](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dmidecode&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3).

> More often than not, information contained in the DMI tables is
>   inaccurate, incomplete or simply wrong.

Comment: It might also be possible that the motherboard is designed for multiple CPUs, but has one of the sockets removed, but the board's programming left alone.